# Error with envelope sending in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have written a macro to automatically send a range of an excel sheet in the body of the mail and also to add as an attachment another range of the sheet. When I run it it says that there is an error (Invalid procedure or call argument) in the line where the attachment is. I am providing the code below.

The line with the error

```
.Item.attachments.Add (Sheets("New Report").Range("A1:X93").Text)
```

The entire code

```
Sub EmailsNewReport()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ToArray As String
    Dim CCArray As String
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Content As String

    Sheets("New Report").Select
    ToArray = "feliagkas.pg@pg.com"
    Subject = "Hello"
    Content = "Hey"
    Sheets("New Report").Range("B3:P31").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With Sheets("New Report").MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = Content
    .Item.To = ToArray
    .Item.Subject = Subject
    .Item.attachments.Add (Sheets("New Report").Range("A1:X93").Text)
    .Item.Send
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `Sheets("New Report").Range("A1:X93").Text`? It needs to be a fully qualified filename.

Comment: Ah.. its a range inside the Active workbook, in the sheet("New Report")

Comment: Attachments have to be files, not ranges.

Comment: So, in this case I have to create a new workbook and a new sheet to add my range in there and then send it as a file?

Comment: This should help, as it can turn a range into an html file: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Thank braX for you help!! However I will try to find a less complicated method!! I have checked this one before and I dont think I need to change the format of my code so much in order for it to work!! nevertheless, thank you again!!